# CSS Sprite "Moves" on mouseover at certain zoom magnifications

Tags: zooming, mouseover, css-sprites

The sprite below works, but at certain magnifications, the top of the image moves down a drop on mouseover, creating an unwanted movement effect. The problem occurs on multiple browsers. Any clues? Thanks in advance.

```
<style>
.test   {width:107px; height:51px;
background:url(http://img706.imageshack.us/img706/6812/navr.gif) no-repeat 0 0; }
.test:hover {background:url(http://img706.imageshack.us/img706/6812/navr.gif) no-repeat 0 -51px; }
</style>
<div class="test"></div>
```

EDIT: I've looked at a few other sprite examples on the web, and I've seen this happening on other sites! I spent quite a long time researching this, but I have yet to see one page anywhere mentioning this specific issue with css sprites!

My intuition tells me that there is absolutely nothing that I can do in my code to fix this problem, and that the solution lies within the creation of the gif itself. I hope I'm wrong and that there is some silver CSS bullet!

EDIT #2: I tried with a "horizontal" sprite, i.e. the 2nd navbar was to the right of the first instead of below. Results: fewer magnifications produced the distortion, but I found a horizontal shift more jarring on the eyes than a vertical shift.

Until I find a solution to this, I think that sprites are not something I'll be using: I'd rather have the client wait another second or two to get the images than have a page with unprofessional-looking shifts.

Answer (score 0):

normally i use background-position

`#menu li a{background:url('/resources/menuIcons.png');display:block;float:left;height:70px;text-indent:-9999px;width:70px;}`
`#menu li.home a{background-position:0px 0px;}`
`#menu li.home a:hover{background-position:0px -70px;}`

Try structuring your code like that

Comment: Your proposal is equivalent to my code, just using different syntax, so does not solve problem. I tried it just to be 100% sure:
    <style>
    .test2   {width:107px; height:51px;
    background:url(http://img706.imageshack.us/img706/6812/navr.gif); background-position:0px 0px; }
    .test2:hover {background:url(http://img706.imageshack.us/img706/6812/navr.gif); background-position:0 -51px; }
    </style>
    <div class="test2"></div>